# 2 SiteCollections in same web app - what is special about the root site collection?

Tags: site-collection, stsadm

So, I have these 2 site collections within a single web app at port 83:

1. Main Site Collection: /
2. Nested Site Collection: /sites/custom/

Again, these are 2 separate isolation boundaries.. each is assigned to it's own content database...

For the main collection, I can run these 2 commands in stsadm all day long.. with no problems:

```
stsadm -o deletesite -url http://devSP1.contoso.local:83/
stsadm -o createsite -url http://devSP1.contoso.local:83/ -owneremail me@contoso.com -ownerlogin CONTOSO\me -siteTemplate "STS#1" -description "This is a dev site"
```

No errors. The database is not dropped between calls or anything like that.

If I run these commands, however, the 'createsite' command fails...

```
stsadm -o deletesite -url http://devSP1.contoso.local:83/sites/custom/
stsadm -o createsite -url http://devSP1.contoso.local:83/sites/custom/ -owneremail me@contoso.com -ownerlogin CONTOSO\me -siteTemplate "STS#1" -description "This is a dev site"
```

and I've lost my content db, etc. I have to go into central admin to recreate my SiteCollection before I can run my 'createsite' command.

Here's the error, fwiw:

> The URL '/sites/custom/' is invalid.  It may contain illegal
>   characters, or be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally understand where my knowledge gap was tripping me up. I totally was naive about how Managed Paths (and their resulting associated site collections) work.

In my original question, I compared experiences between two different site collections.
However, the first site collection was a *root site collection* hanging off an *Explicit* managed path, while the other site collection was NOT a root site collection as it hung like a leaf off of a *wildcard* managed path.

Running a 'delete' stsadm command gets you different results depending on whether the site collection is root or not.

Now, I've got 2 site collections:

1. Main Site Collection:   /
2. Nested Site Collection: /custom/

and this time I created the 2nd one as *explicit*. So, the resulting /custom/ site is a root collection site similar to the default/first one.

Now I can run my stsadm commands in a repeated fashion as desired and get the results I was wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't matching up here. Your error is about /custom/ross/, but your commands don't mention ross. Are you trying to create another site collection under custom?

For you to create site collections, you need to use a managed path. By default, /sites/ is setup as a managed path on your web application (see Central Admin > Manage web applications > Managed paths in Ribbon). You'll have to create a new managed path if you want to create additional site collections elsewhere.

HTH

Comment: oops.. I have genericized my site collection examples but pasted in the 'real' error message w/o making it match. Fixed.

Comment: ok, so, sticking with my example above, I currenly have this managed path already existing: /sites/ (as you said). I know how to use central admin to create a new SiteCollection at /sites/custom. I don't know how to do this via stsadm, I guess.

Comment: For SP2007 - stsadm -o addpath -url http://managed path -type {Explicitinclusion | Wildcardinclusion} : see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845(v=office.12).aspx. :: For SP2010 - New-SPManagedPath [-RelativeURL] "RelativeURL" -WebApplication WebApplication : see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: In stsadm cmd CreateSite commands is only used if you want to create a site collection with its own content DB.

You cannot use CreateSite cmd if you want to create a Site collection in existing Content DB.